# Unicorn / KGIO fails to install on Mountain Lion w/ ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, unicorn

The main error message is:

```
checking size of struct RFile in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

kgio successfully installs on ruby 1.9.1, using RVM, but fails on ruby 1.9.3. I'm on Mountain Lion with Xcode + Command Line Tools installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably this bug in RVM: [Issue #1157](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1157)

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

Didn't find the root cause, but using `rbenv` instead of `rvm` seems to have fixed it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Changing line 597 of .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb to this will work around the problem:

return Integer((v=f.gets) ? v : 0)